# How to paint lots of images in some kind of surface with pan/zoom?

Tags: android, image, zooming, pan

I'm new to Android but I have some Java knowledge and I've started reading the Android documentation and some book but I'm in the very beginning. But even if I've read more, it would be hard to know the recommended way to do what I want without real experience in Android programming...

What I need is to have some kind of surface where I can paint/draw/whatever lots of images, probably PNGs with transparency. I need to be able to pan around and zoom this surface with all those images. I also need to be able to click on any of those images and know which one was clicked.

I've been reading the [One Finger Zoom Tutorial](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/developerworld/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/) from Sony Ericsson developers and it looks like a good solution for what I want to do. But I'm a little confused because that code is for a single bitmap image and I need to have lots of them drawn on some surface/canvas.

I'm thinking of two ways to accomplish this:

1. Adapt the code somehow so I can draw each image on the `Canvas` (from `onDraw()`) but that's where I'm confused, I don't see how can I accomplish this cause the current code is simple for a single image, there's not much to account for.
2. Overlay all my images into a single bitmap and use that bitmap as a background for the `Canvas` (once again, from `onDraw()`). I could save those images position in the `Canvas` into an Array or something and use that as reference to see if the user clicked in any of them. I suppose this is possible this way?

So, in reality, here's what I'm asking:

- If the first described method above is better, please help me understand how can I achieve such a thing.
- If the second one is better, could you give me some hints how can I overlay all those images, save their positions and detect them with a touch event?
- If there's a better a way to handle all this, I would love to hear about it.

This is for a very basic game I'm thinking of developing and before you go that way, OpenGL is too much for what I need and I want to take one step at a time. First learn Android programming and someday learn OpenGL.

Answer (score 2):

Why not see if you can use (or extend) the ItemizedOverlay as used with a MapView. The ItemizedOverlay enables you to add 'markers', usually PNG drawables which can all be different. They respond to Touch events or Gestures and are laid out according to screen locations (which are translated into map coordinates via the MapProjection). (I use them in a mapping app I'm working on). The layouts have their own draw() method which does require a MapView, but you may be able to null this or possibly disable any map layer from showing and show some other kind of background - some experimentation needed here.

Comment: Remember, I'm new to Android programming, I have no idea what you are talking about. Besides, per your description, it seemed a lot more complicated than one of the methods I described in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Let me get this straight. You want multiple images each of them touchable? 
If so, maybe you should think a little bit more abstractly.

Maybe it would be easier to treat each images as a view object (just an idea) since view objects already come built in with onTouchListeners

Comment: Not all of them need to be touchable, not necessarily, but what do you mean by thinking "more abstractly"? What exactly would be the problem with all of them being touchable? The images itself don't need to be touchable (read point 2). And what are you referring to when you say "view object"? And how could I use that with the SonyEricsoon One Finger Zoom code? P.S: You should add a comment next time.

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution (inserted below) is best in my opinion.

> Adapt the code somehow so I can draw each image on the Canvas (from onDraw()) but that's where I'm confused, I don't see how can I accomplish this cause the current code is simple for a single image, there's not much to account for.

Depending on your use-case, I'd make your View contain your images in an appropriate structure, An ArrayList (if you're not doing to many random inserts/deletions) maybe. On the onDraw() method just iterate down this list of bitmaps and draw each of them.

In order to make them touchable, use the setOnTouchListener method (or override onTouch() if you're subclassing View, I didn't read the link you provided) to provide a handler that will be called whenever the view is called. The handler will be given the location of every touch event, which you can use to determine which, if any, image was touched. How you test collisions will of course depend upon the specifics of your game.

This method is not the cleanest, but it is the simplest (and fastest depending on how you do it!). Personally, OpenGL is intimidating but overcoming the learning curve will pay off greatly in the future (like vim or emacs!), it was made for this kind of use-case.

For more information on handling touch events, see this link. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Comment: I'm still confused on how to draw each image on the Canvas, taking the code from SonyEricsson into account. That's why I suggested number two, seemed easier to me to paint all those images into a bitmap and use that bitmap with the SonyEricsson code. But since I'm new to Android development, I don't which is better/easier.

Comment: In the current version you have an onDraw method that calls "canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mRectSrc, mRectDst, mPaint);" what you would do is wrap that call in a loop, something like for(Thing b : game_objects) { canvas.drawBitmap(b.bitmap, b.source, b.dest, b.paint);} tangentally, there are a few more overloaded drawBitmap methods that might be better for you.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into that when I get into this project again.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old, but I have one solution and still one question :-)

In order to manage to drop several images, I create an ArrayList with this class (ColorBall):

```java
private Bitmap img; // the image of the ball
private int coordX = 0; // the x coordinate at the canvas
private int coordY = 0; // the y coordinate at the canvas
private int id; // gives every ball his own id, for now not necessary
private static int count = 1;
private boolean goRight = true;
private boolean goDown = true;
private int height = 50;
private int width = 50; 
private Rect mRectSrc = new Rect();
private Rect mRectDst = new Rect();
```

In the view, when I click, if I have clicked inside the limits of an image, I modify the coordX and coordY (easy to check with `if (x > ball.getX() && x < ball.getX()+ball.getWidth() && y > ball.getY() && y < ball.getY()+ball.getHeight())`. ).

In the OnDraw event, I just go through all the elements in the Array and I paint them where it corresponds.

```java
for (ColorBall ball : colorballs) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(), null);
}
```

However, I'm still stucked with the zooming. I'm trying to solve it as in the following post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422759/zoom-a-bitmap-with-drawbitmap-and-rectangles-android), but I'm still blocked with it :-(

Cheers

Comment: It may be old but I still didn't got the answer I was looking for (until now maybe). The fact is, I never tackled this problem after posting the question, never had time to begin my little game idea. But I'm sure to test your approach when I find time (whenever that may be).