# Zoom a bitmap with drawBitmap and rectangles - Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, zooming

I'm developing a small image editor. Basically, the user can insert some images in a canvas, and through interaction with the fingers moving them around. I'm having some trouble with the Zooming. I have followed the idea of this [tutorial](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/wp/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1) to use a bitmap, and to apply transformations to two rectangles. Afterwards, if we draw the bitmap over the canvas with `android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)`, the transformation is applied. So far, is not working for me.

I store all the images in an array of images, `ColorBall`. When I detect there is a zoom gesture, and only if it was over a certain image (this works so far), I apply over that image the transformations (the values are dummy, just wanted to check if it works):

```java
colorballs.get(balID-1).getmRectDst().left   = getLeft();
colorballs.get(balID-1).getmRectDst().top    = getTop();
colorballs.get(balID-1).getmRectDst().right  = getRight();
colorballs.get(balID-1).getmRectDst().bottom = getBottom();

colorballs.get(balID-1).getmRectSrc().left   += 10;
colorballs.get(balID-1).getmRectSrc().top    += 10;
colorballs.get(balID-1).getmRectSrc().right  += 10;
colorballs.get(balID-1).getmRectSrc().bottom += 10;
```

On the OnDraw event, for all the pictures in the array I locate them, and then I scale them using the rectangles. So far, the part of scaling is not working:

```java
//draw the balls on the canvas
for (ColorBall ball : colorballs) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), ball.getmRectSrc(), ball.getmRectDst(), mPaintBalls);
}
```

Any suggestion of what can I be missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i used same example for zooming images in canvas but nothing ......have you solved it ? if yes then tell me the way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding to the bottom/right, so instead of zooming you are actually just shifting the background source to the right ten.

```
colorballs.get(balID-1).getmRectSrc().right  -= 10;
colorballs.get(balID-1).getmRectSrc().bottom -= 10;
```